# error: call of overloaded 'abs(double)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I've searched for answers, and can't find one that fits my very simple case.

Why on earth is abs only working on integers? I can't perform this operation?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float someVariable = abs(-4.22);
    cout << someVariable;
}
```

Note, I'm using http://cpp.sh to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the math library, like this:

```
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Ah okay, I had to `#include <math.h>` for it to work. Thank you for your help. But I'm almost sure abs() can be used for real numbers, no (I'm reading that in C no, but C++ yes)!?

Comment: Yes correct @aName, see my updated, by the way, you asked a good question, +1!

Comment: I don't think you need `fabs` if you include `math.h` (according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers), both `<cxxx>` and `<xxx.h>` should declare the same names, just in different namespaes). [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad539e762e8923a6) `abs` from `math.h` seems to work on real numbers just fine.

Comment: This is what I thought too @HolyBlackCat, but please take a look at my first Live Demo. There I have included `<math.h>`. Changing `fabs()` to `abs()` results in an error!

Comment: Curiously, in my working environment, simply including `math.h` and `abs(-4.22)` worked just fine!!

Comment: @gsamaras It works in my demo link too. The site you used seems to use GCC 4.9.2, so maybe it's an old compiler bug?

Answer (score 2):

abs has different implementations depending on how it is included.

To get floating point, then you need to

```
#include <cmath>
```

Resultant program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float someVariable = abs(-4.22);
    cout << someVariable;
}
```

Reference [cppreference abs(float)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)

Answer (score 1):

`std::abs` takes any of:

- [`int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)
- `long`
- `long long`
- [`float`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)
- `double`
- `long double`

However, prior to C++17, unless you `#include <cmath>` then only the integer overloads (first three listed) are available. You're passing a `float` which converts equally well to any three of them, so the compiler can't tell which one you wanted.

If you *did* want an integer overload, you'd use a cast to `int`, `long` or `long long` as appropriate.

But you don't: you want to trigger the `float` overload, so bring it into scope with `#include <cmath>` and then it should automatically be picked because you're passing a `float`.

In fact, as it is, you're just *getting lucky* that even the integer overloads are available, because you never `#include`d `<cstdlib>`; your toolchain's `<iostream>` must have *just so happened* to do it for you. Always include the proper headers according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

abs() is declared in cmath header. So,  if you want to use abs(), You need to include cmath in your code like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float someVariable = abs(-4.22);
    cout << someVariable;
}
```

Note : From C++11 and more versions , We can use abs() in the following way :

```
double abs (double x);
float abs (float x);
long double abs (long double x);
double abs (T x);           // additional overloads for integral types
```

Reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/